# Android TextView Simple Animation SetX

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

Hi currently I want to create a simple animation setting the X position of TextView with delayed.. here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    float ctr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ctr = 0;
        final TextView p1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1);

        while (ctr <= 100) {
            p1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    p1.setX(ctr);
                    ctr++;
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

}
```

Currently this code only delayed by 5sec then instantly position the x position of the Textview, want I want is slowly position the TextView..
Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) or an [`ObjectAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html):

**`ViewPropertyAnimator`**:

```
float ctr = 0f;
while (ctr <= 100f) {
    p1.animate().x(ctr).setDuration(5000).start();
    ctr++;
}
```

**`ObjectAnimator`**

```
final ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(p1, "x", 100f);
oa.setDuration(5000);
oa.start();
```

To use the animation on devices below 3.0 (Honeycomb), take a look at [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/).